# After installing Big Sur on my macbook, running tmcbeans gives me error msg "The JDK is missing and is required to run some NetBeans modules"

Tags: java, installation, netbeans

After the error msg, it says "Please use the --jdkhome command line option to specify a JDK installation".
So when I run command `/usr/libexec/java_home -V`
I get these

```
1.8.261.12 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java" /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
1.8.0_241 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_241.jdk/Contents/Home
```

And I tried using --jdkhome by typing like this

```
./tmcbeans --jdkhome /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_241.jdk/Contents/Home
```

And I still get the same error msg. I also tried this.

```
export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_241.jdk/Contents/Home"
```

This still don't work. Another option suggested was trying to edit /etc/netbeans.conf, but this is tmcbeans(netbeans with tmc ide) so it doesn't have such config file. I installed this app from MOOC Hilsinki course. How can I fix this error? Please help.

Comment: I have soled this issue by  1. Reset jdkhome path in tmcbeans.config 2. Delete both cache and directory file found under About tmcbeans.

Comment: Same mistake. I reinstalled without success. Finally I formatted and did a clean install. JavaHome configured ... still not working. Any solution?

Comment: Did you set jdkhome path manually in tmcbeans.config file? Like jdkhome= /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_271.jdk/Contents/Home

Comment: No... mostly because now I can't even install NetBeans, it tells me the JDK can't be found.

Comment: You need to do something like this in your terminal then -->  
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_271.jdk/Contents/Home

After type this ---> export CLASSPATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar